# Access hibernate properties from Grails service?

Tags: hibernate, grails

How can I access Hibernate properties from a Grails Service?

In this instance I have to use `createSQLQuery` for a legacy database and need access to the `hibernate.default_schema` property in order to build a valid SQL statement.

```
class MyService {
    def sessionFactory

    def getRows() {
        def session = sessionFactory.currentSession
        session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM schema.table").list()
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

There is a quirk with Grails 2.x multiple datasources and the setting of Hibernate properties.  Properties set in additional datasources are applied to the default datasource.

The properties must be set in the `hibernate` object instead of the `datasource` object:

```
datasource_ds2 {
    . . .
}
hibernate_ds2 {
    default_schema = "schema"
}
```

They can then be accessed from the `hibernate` config in grailsApplication:

```
def grailsApplication
assert grailsApplication.config.hibernate_ds2.default_schema == "schema"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're stored in the Config object, e.g.:

```
class MyService {

    def grailsApplication
    def sessionFactory

    def getRows() {

        def defaultSchema = grailsApplication.config.hibernate.default_schema
        def session = sessionFactory.currentSession
        session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM ${defaultSchema}.table").list()
    }
}
```

Comment: I didnt realize the properties were available in the Grails config.  I kept trying to back into it from the session and datasource.  Many thanks.